# Get timestamp from DatePicker AND TimePicker

Tags: java, android, timestamp, timepicker

I have an app in which a user sets a date and time using a DatePicker and a TimePicker. I am trying to save the information as a timestamp. I am currently getting the timestamp based on the date picked by the user (see code below):

```
                Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
                final Calendar c = cal.getInstance();
                int mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR); // current year
                int mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH); // current month
                int mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH); // current day
                // date picker dialog
                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(AddEventActivity.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                                  int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                // set day of month , month and year value in the edit text
                                txtDate.setText(dayOfMonth + "/"
                                        + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year);
                                c.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                                timestamp = c.getTimeInMillis();
                            }
```

This works fine, but since I don't give a time, it sets the time to the time I create the item.
For example, say I set an event on 27/4/2019 at 19:00, and save it at 13:30, the timestamp recorded reads 27/4/2019 at 13:30.

The code for my TimePicker is below:

```
        txtTime.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Calendar mcurrentTime = Calendar.getInstance();
                int hour = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                int minute = mcurrentTime.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                TimePickerDialog mTimePicker;
                mTimePicker = new TimePickerDialog(AddEventActivity.this, new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker timePicker, int selectedHour, int selectedMinute) {
                        //adding extra 0 to the front of 1 digit hours and minutes so format is consistent.
                        String hourFormat = String.format("%02d", selectedHour);
                        String minFormat = String.format("%02d", selectedMinute);
                        txtTime.setText(hourFormat + ":" + minFormat);
                    }
                }, hour, minute, true);
                mTimePicker.show();
            }
        });
```

Is there a way to combine the date and time selected to create an accurate timestamp?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a class level Calendar instance and let's instantiate it the way you did it earlier:

```
Calendar combinedCal = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
```

So when you select date, set value as you do:

```
combinedCal.set(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
```

When you select time, just set selected hours and minutes to the same instance:

```
combinedCal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, selectedHour);
combinedCal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, selectedMinute);
```

Comment: You are a lifesaver! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

Timestamp contains the date and time you selected from Datepicker and Timepicker

```
    timepicker = (Timepicker)findViewById(R.id.timepicker);
    datepicker = (Datepicker)findViewById(R.id.datepicker);

    int year = datepicker.getYear();
    int month = datepicker.getMonth();
    int day = datepicker.getDay();
    int hour= timepicker.getCurrentHour();
    int minute = timepicker.getCurrentMinute();


    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MONTH, month);
    calendar.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, day);
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, hour);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, minute);
    calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
    Long timestamp = calendar.getTimeInMills();


    System.out.println(timestamp);
```

Answer (score 0):

i had a similar issue while i was fetching dates so what i did was create a string which i used to pick the current date and time the merge it to create a perfect a time stamp like so

```
final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
                mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
                mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);


                DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(ServiceManDetails.this,
                        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                                String month,day;
                                if(monthOfYear<9){
                                    month="0"+ (monthOfYear + 1);
                                    if(dayOfMonth<10){
                                        day="0"+dayOfMonth;
                                    }else{
                                        day=dayOfMonth+"";
                                    }
                                }else{
                                    month= (monthOfYear + 1)+"";
                                    if(dayOfMonth<10){
                                        day="0"+dayOfMonth;
                                    }else{
                                        day=dayOfMonth+"";
                                    }
                                }
                                //String selectedday=dayOfMonth + "/" + (monthOfYear + 1) + "/" + year;

                                pickedDate=year + "/" + month + "/" + day;



                                final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
                                mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
                                mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

                                // Launch Time Picker Dialog
                                TimePickerDialog timePickerDialog = new TimePickerDialog(ServiceManDetails.this,
                                        new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                                            @Override
                                            public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                                                  int minute) {

                                                String hr,min;
                                                if(hourOfDay<10){
                                                    hr="0"+hourOfDay;
                                                    if(minute<10){
                                                       min="0"+minute;
                                                    }else{
                                                        min=minute+"";
                                                    }
                                                }else{
                                                    hr=hourOfDay+"";
                                                    if(minute<10){
                                                        min="0"+minute;
                                                    }else{
                                                        min=minute+"";
                                                    }
                                                }
                                                time=hr + ":" + min + ":00";
                                                date=pickedDate+" "+time;

                                                scheduleDialog(date);
                                            }
                                        }, mHour, mMinute, true);
                                timePickerDialog.show();

                            }
                        }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
                datePickerDialog.show();
```

also i dint want to set miliseconds so i set the date automatically set the seconds as 00 you can also add milliseconds as 000